# PHP - If (condição) no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, lógica

Seguinte, tenho 4 postagens em um post type serviços.

Noivas, Day Spa, Medicina Estética e Salão

```
<div class="service-content <?php if( $post_title == 'Noivas' ) echo "qwp-content"; ?>">
<?php var_dump($post_title); ?>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
</div><!-- /.qwp-content -->

CSS:
.qwp-content { 
    font-size: 1.444rem;
    text-align: center; 

    p:nth-child(odd) {
      color: #000;  
      padding: 7px;
      background: #C5C2B3; 
    }
  }

  .service-content { 
    font-size: 1.444rem;
  }
```

Tava fazendo assim, mas não saco tanto de lógica e tals.

Basicamente, o que quero, é que quando a pessoa acesse Noivas, ele não pegue a classe .qwp-content e pegue só a .service-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso, você precisa apenas alterar o operador.

```
<?php
    $post_title = "Noivas";         
?>

<div class="service-content <?php if( $post_title != 'Noivas' ) echo "qwp-content";  ?>">
    <p> teste </p>
</div>
```

Eu particularmente sugiro que você faça a condição fora da class, para que possa reaproveitar em outro lugar. Ex:

```
<?php
        $post_title = "Não sou noiva";
        $qwp = '';
        if( $post_title != 'Noivas' ) {
            $qwp = "qwp-content";
        }
?>

<div class="service-content <?php echo $qwp ;  ?>">
    <p> teste </p>
</div>

<div class="service-main <?php echo $qwp ;  ?>">
    <p> teste </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Po galera, muito obrigado, pra mim que estou engatinhando no Wordpress e PHP, programação no geral, essa ajuda é muito valida, tô mó felizão que consegui fazer de forma certa minha primeira condiçãozinha hehe.

Fiz da seguinte forma e deu certo:

<div class="qwp-content  <?php if( $post_title != 'Noivas' ) echo "service-content"; ?>">
              <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div><!-- /.qwp-content -->

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer assim.

```
<div class="service-content <?php echo get_the_title() != 'Noivas' ? 'qwp-content' : '' ?>">
```